# Script that runs "reg add" as admin

Tags: cmd, registry, admin

I need help in making a script (bat, vbs, whatever) that runs at startup as a different user (admin) the following command:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome /f /v RestoreOnStartup /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

I've tried combining that with "runas /savecred /user:administrator", without any success..

**Background**

On my work computer, in Chrome, the Startup Options are disabled. The only way to change them is through the registry, but after every restart, it reverts back to its original form (*Continue where left off* disabled).

So I would like a script that does enables it every time, so I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have default settings use `RunAs` with the administrator account, except it will be disabled (but if it isn't is will run elevated as if standard settings apply).

**This is a security not a programming question**.

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

You then have to allow logon with blank password in Local Security Policy.

Then

```
runas /user server\administrator "notepad.exe \"c:\windows\win.ini\""
```

The server is YOUR computer name.

I just turn offf UAC.

Comment: I can't seem to find "You then have to allow logon with blank password in Local Security Policy.". If it's "Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only", that is Enabled and greyed out. When I run your runas command I get the help reply

Comment: If I use "runas /user:server\administrator", it asks me for the password and then says unknown user name or bad password

Comment: It is that, turn UAC off. This is from my post re your server name _*The server is YOUR computer name*_